# How to add csp, x-frame-option header Azure app service ( nodejs, react)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-app-configuration

We are using Azure app service for my react application . We are serving react build artifacts from the azure app service (the app service is using nodejs 14). Here i wanted to

```
add content-security-policy header in web.config file.
Add x-frame-option - sameorigin
Remove x-powered-by: express header
```

But it didn't reflect in the app service configuration after modifying in `web.config` file. What should I do?

my web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value=".." />
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />                          
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `web.config` as per your question in react application and which is working locally and in Azure like below:-

I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu) and this [Blog](https://medium.com/ms-club-of-sliit/deploy-a-react-app-using-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-57643313f53c) to deploy react app in Azure App service and to configure below steps with advanced tools Kudu. The following code snippet is adapted from the linked blog by [Ashen Wijesingha](https://medium.com/@a.d.wijesingha):

```
<configuration>   
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>   
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- In Azure Web App > Advanced Tools click on **Go** in Browse Directory select `wwwroot`

[image]

[image]

Deployment [status](https://i.imgur.com/OcE0wxR.png).

[image]